# Is there a $4$-component link such that upon removing any one of them you get the Borromean link?

Tags: knot-theory

Is there a $4$-component link such that upon removing any one of them you get the [Borromean link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borromean_rings)?

I've managed to get close but not quite. What I have gets me something similar to the Borromean link but two of the components actually form what I think is the [Whitehead link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_link).

Comment: There is a [numberphile video on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6Ml4AEt0kk), where Professor John Hunton from the University of Leicester states that there is a generalization of Borromean links only for odd numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort of think of the Borromean rings as lying on three faces of a tetrahedron, with the center triangle of the usual presentation at a vertex.  By adding a component corresponding to the fourth face in a way so that the link has tetrahedral symmetry, you get the following:

[image: 4-component link]

While the outer component looks funny, it is the same as any of the other three, in the sense that there is an isotopy of the link sending this diagram to itself, but moving an inner component to the outer component.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Clever way to distort the fourth component in a way that becomes a normal circle when one of the other ones is removed. I'm guessing that since the construction is done with tetrahedral symmetry, an $n$-component equivalent might not be so easy to construct. Or do you think one can do the same thing starting with an $n$-simplex and then project onto $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @DarthGeek Looking at this carefully again this morning, I think I need to retract my claim that it has tetrahedral symmetry.  It might be possible to do such a construction for certain polyhedra with three faces per vertex, with one component per face, but I'm not sure what condition allows for the property that removing all but three around a particular vertex leaves the Borromean rings.

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially the same answer as that of Kyle, but with a more artistic aproach. If you vote this anwser, please vote Kyle's too since he's the one that inspired this design in the first place.

[image]

And here's the version with five components (two must be removed to obtain the Borromean Link).

[image]

Comment: Nice realization! It's interesting that it can be done with only triangles.

Answer (score 2):

Translating to Mathematica  the answer of Kyle, via the following diagram

[image]

we obtain the following picture

[image]

The corresponding Jones polynomial is

[image]

The corresponding Khovanov-Poincaré polynomial is

[image]

One application in quantum computing is as follows

[image]